# how to install android SDK zip file on IntelliJ Ultimate?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

for this error:
[image]

and these is my android SDK files:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use sdkmanager from commandline:**

1. Open up a command prompt
2. use tools/bin/sdkmanager.bat (`cd tools/bin/`)
3. `sdkmanager --list` command shows the available packages you can download
4. install a plarform: e.g.: `sdkmanager platforms;android-26` command will install the newest platform

**Configure Intellij:**

1. Configure-Project Defaults-Project Structure-SDKs
2. Add Android sdk (Browse the downloaded platform's directory, it is in the tools\platform directory)